# Batch file to perform a looped search based on the line items of a text file

Tags: windows, search, for-loop, batch-file

I have been reading great posts in this forum and got close to what I want to do but couldn't figure out the exact code.

I want to create a windows batch file to do following:

- Perform a looped search for each line item of a text file (this is a list of keyword) to locate files in a a specific directory
- For this search partial match is okay.
- Each time a file is found, move it to a predefined directory (e.g. C:\temp\search_results)

Thanks.

Comment: It can be done in batch ... but you may use free unix utilities ported to windows (for example AWK) that are more flexible

Comment: I can not see any problems in your code. Perhaps you should try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

FIND /i "%A%" ... can't work, the name of the FOR-Varibale is %%A
And the second proble: With FIND you check the content of the file not the name.
And you should use indention to avoid too much parenthesis.

You better try

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (%listfile%) DO (
    FOR %%f in (%searchdir%\*) do ( 
        set "filename=%%~f"
        set replaced=!filename:%%A=!
        if !replaced! NEQ !filename! (
           echo !filename! contains '%%A'
        )
    )
)
```

It tries to replace %%A inside of the filename with .
If the replaced is not equal the filename, the filename must contain %%A

Comment: Thank you Jeb. This helps me a lot. I really like how you compare the string with the file name. I now need play with different variations of the criteria string. Eg. the line item in the file might be "Stephen King" and the variations of the filename could be:
- Stephen King
- King Stephen
- Stephen_King
etc.
I will try to capture all of variations. Thanks again.

Comment: You can split your string "Stephen King" into tokens "Stephen" and "King" and test if all tokens are present in your filename

Answer (score 1):

I'm not running Windows at the moment, so I can only post some ideas, not the solution.

1) Use `for /f` to iterate over file contents.

2) Use `find "%Keyword%" %SourceDir%` to get the list of matching files. You will have to parse out file names from the output of `find`.

2a) As an alternative, you can iterate over files in the source dir (with nested `for`) and call `find` for each file, discarding its output and using its exit code (`%ERRORLEVEL%`) to decide whether the file matches (it will return 0 if there is a match and nonzero if there is no match). Something like this:

```
for %%F in (%SourceDir%\*) do (
    find "%Keyword%" %%F > nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (echo File %%F matches) else (echo File %%F does not match)
)
```

3) Move matching files with `move`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code but not sure if I am in the right track. Here is my setup:
list.txt file contents are (my keywords for the filename search) --

```
one
two
five
ten
six
```

f1 folder contains --

```
four.txt
one.txt
three.txt
```

I want to move the matching ones to F2 folder, but the code simplicity I am using echo instead.

My code is:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion


SET listfile=D:\batchtest\list.txt
SET searchdir=D:\batchtest\f1

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (%listfile%) DO (

FOR %%f in (%searchdir%\*) do (FIND /i "%A%" %%f
    if errorlevel 1 (
echo Search failed) else (
echo Search successful
)   
)
)
)
```

It is running but not finding matching filenames.

Thanks.